# If $HK = KH$ and $H \cap K$ is normal in $H$, is $K$ normal in $HK$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Title says it all.  Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$.  If $HK = KH$ and $H \cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, is it true that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$?

Since this question is of a general nature, I wanted to share the solution (as I understand it, this is consistent with MSE guidelines).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP already knows the answer.

Comment: @verret: MSE [encourages](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) this sort of behavior; it's the opposite of a reason to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False.  Take any internal semidirect product $G = K \rtimes H$ where $K$ is normal in $G$ but $H$ is not.  Then $HK = KH = G$ and $H \cap K = \{e \}$, the trivial subgroup.  Thus $H \cap K$ is normal in $K$, but $H$ is not normal in $HK$.